# If things travel at different time rates due to relativity wouldn't one of them disappear from my perspective?

Tags: general-relativity, time, time-dilation

If I travel to a 3d location where Einstein was known to have existed at some other time, I do not expect to see him, because his 4d location is different! Why then can I send a clock around a black hole and bring it back, verify that it's different from my clock???? How can I look at two clocks at the same time, if they are in different 4d locations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two clocks traveled different paths.  Even in Newtonian physcics, the two paths can have different lengths in space.  If two cars clear their trip odometers, then travel two different roads to the same location, they may have different values on arrival.   In general relativity, the paths can also have diffferent lengths in time, so the clocks can similarly both arrive at the same (or nearby) space time coordinates depicting different times.

Comment: A clock is like an odometer for 4d space time, different paths to the event = different readings when you get there... Got it! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Your 2 clocks travelled on 2 different worldlines through 4D spacetime since they were synchronised, but now they are united at almost the same spacetime location (event), so you can easily compare them.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is interesting because the answer permits to show what time exactly is.

Time is twofold: Each particle produces its own **proper time** (its own aging according to its own clock). In a second step, the proper time of different particles may be synchronized within the coordinates of an arbitrary observer (**coordinate time**).

The second time concept of coordinate time is very important, because without it there would be no relation between the proper time of two particles: You cannot represent the proper time of two particles in the same coordinate system.

Example: Two particles are approaching the same point P in space. If they are reaching point P at the same moment, there will be a particle event (collision), if they are reaching point P one after the other, there will be no particle event. In order to predict if there will be a particle event or not, the proper time of both particles is not sufficient, additionally there is needed the coordinate time of an arbitrary observer (which may be one of the particles) in order to calculate the time dilation factor of both particles. Such an observer will draw the two worldlines in his own Minkowski diagram, in the form of coordinate time, which is the time after time dilation. Proper time (which is time before time dilation) will not be shown in this diagram, it may only be calculated arithmetically.

In summary, the answer to your question is: there is no problem at all, within the twofold time concept, coordinate time is synchronizing the different proper times by the means of time dilation and permits to take both of them into account.